# Increased performance for pickle.dumps through monkey patching DEFAULT_PROTOCOL?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pickle

I've noticed it can make quite a substantial difference in terms of speed, 
if you specify the protocol used in pickle.dumps via argument or if you
monkey patch pickle.DEFAULT_PROTOCOL for the desired protocol version.

On Python 3.6, `pickle.DEFAULT_PROTOCOL` is 3 and 
`pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL` is 4.

For objects up to a certain length it seems to be faster setting
DEFAULT_PROTOCOL to 4 instead of passing `protocol=4` as argument.

In my tests for example, with setting pickle.DEFAULT_PROTOCOL to 4 and pickling
a list with length 1 by calling `pickle.dumps(packet_list_1)` takes 481 ns, while calling with `pickle.dumps(packet_list_1, protocol=4)` takes 733 ns, a staggering ~52% speed-penalty for passing protocol explicitly instead of falling back to default (which was set to 4 before).

```
  """
  (stackoverflow insists this to be formatted as code:)

  pickle.DEFAULT_PROTOCOL = 4
  pickle.dumps(packet) vs pickle.dumps(packet, protocol=4):

  (stackoverflow insists this to be formatted as code:)
  For a list with length 1 it's 481ns vs 733ns (~52% penalty).
  For a list with length 10 it's 763ns vs 999ns (~30% penalty).
  For a list with length 100 it's 2.99 µs vs 3.21 µs (~7% penalty).
  For a list with length 1000 it's 25.8 µs vs 26.2 µs (~1.5% penalty).
  For a list with length 1_000_000 it's 32 ms vs 32.4 ms (~1.13% penalty).
  """
```

I've found this behaviour for instances, lists, dicts and arrays, which is
all I tested so far. The effect diminishes with object size.

For dicts I noticed the effect turning at some point into the opposite, so that
for a length 10**6 dict (with unique integer values) it's faster to explicitly
pass protocol=4 as argument (269ms) than relying on default set to 4 (286ms).

```
 """
 pickle.DEFAULT_PROTOCOL = 4 
 pickle.dumps(packet) vs pickle.dumps(packet, protocol=4):

 For a dict with length 1 it's 589 ns vs 811 ns (~38% penalty).
 For a dict with length 10 it's 1.59 µs vs 1.81 µs (~14% penalty).
 For a dict with length 100 it's 13.2 µs vs 12.9 µs (~2,3% penalty).
 For a dict with length 1000 it's 128 µs vs 129 µs (~0.8% penalty).
 For a dict with length 1_000_000 it's 306 ms vs 283 ms (~7.5% improvement).
 """
```

Glimpsing over the pickle source, nothing strikes my eye what might cause
such variations.

**How is this unexpected behaviour explainable?**

**Are there any caveats for setting pickle.DEFAULT_PROTOCOL instead of passing
protocol as argument to take advantage of the improved speed?**

(Timed with IPython's timeit magic on Python 3.6.3, IPython 6.2.1, Windows 7)

Some example code dump:

```
# instances -------------------------------------------------------------
class Dummy: pass

dummy = Dummy()

pickle.DEFAULT_PROTOCOL = 3

"""
>>> %timeit pickle.dumps(dummy)
5.8 µs ± 33.5 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
>>> %timeit pickle.dumps(dummy, protocol=4)
6.18 µs ± 10.4 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
"""
pickle.DEFAULT_PROTOCOL = 4
"""
%timeit pickle.dumps(dummy)
5.74 µs ± 18.8 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
%timeit pickle.dumps(dummy, protocol=4)
6.24 µs ± 26.7 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
"""

# lists -------------------------------------------------------------
packet_list_1 = [*range(1)]

pickle.DEFAULT_PROTOCOL = 3
"""
>>>%timeit pickle.dumps(packet_list_1)
476 ns ± 1.01 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
>>>%timeit pickle.dumps(packet_list_1, protocol=4)
730 ns ± 2.22 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
"""
pickle.DEFAULT_PROTOCOL = 4
"""
>>>%timeit pickle.dumps(packet_list_1)
481 ns ± 2.12 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
>>>%timeit pickle.dumps(packet_list_1, protocol=4)
733 ns ± 2.94 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
"""
# --------------------------
packet_list_10 = [*range(10)]

pickle.DEFAULT_PROTOCOL = 3

"""
>>>%timeit pickle.dumps(packet_list_10)
714 ns ± 3.05 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
>>>%timeit pickle.dumps(packet_list_10, protocol=4)
978 ns ± 24.7 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
"""
pickle.DEFAULT_PROTOCOL = 4
"""
>>>%timeit pickle.dumps(packet_list_10)
763 ns ± 3.16 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
>>>%timeit pickle.dumps(packet_list_10, protocol=4)
999 ns ± 8.34 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
"""
# --------------------------
packet_list_100 = [*range(100)]

pickle.DEFAULT_PROTOCOL = 3

"""
>>>%timeit pickle.dumps(packet_list_100)
2.96 µs ± 5.16 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
>>>%timeit pickle.dumps(packet_list_100, protocol=4)
3.22 µs ± 18.3 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
"""
pickle.DEFAULT_PROTOCOL = 4
"""
>>>%timeit pickle.dumps(packet_list_100)
2.99 µs ± 18.5 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
>>>%timeit pickle.dumps(packet_list_100, protocol=4)
3.21 µs ± 9.11 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
"""
# --------------------------
packet_list_1000 = [*range(1000)]

pickle.DEFAULT_PROTOCOL = 3

"""
>>>%timeit pickle.dumps(packet_list_1000)
26 µs ± 105 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
>>>%timeit pickle.dumps(packet_list_1000, protocol=4)
26.4 µs ± 93.9 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
"""
pickle.DEFAULT_PROTOCOL = 4
"""
>>>%timeit pickle.dumps(packet_list_1000)
25.8 µs ± 110 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
>>>%timeit pickle.dumps(packet_list_1000, protocol=4)
26.2 µs ± 101 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
"""
# --------------------------
packet_list_1m = [*range(10**6)]

pickle.DEFAULT_PROTOCOL = 3

"""
>>>%timeit pickle.dumps(packet_list_1m)
32 ms ± 119 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
>>>%timeit pickle.dumps(packet_list_1m, protocol=4)
32.3 ms ± 141 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
"""
pickle.DEFAULT_PROTOCOL = 4
"""
>>>%timeit pickle.dumps(packet_list_1m)
32 ms ± 52.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
>>>%timeit pickle.dumps(packet_list_1m, protocol=4)
32.4 ms ± 466 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
"""
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's reorganize your %timeit results *by return value*:

```
| DEFAULT_PROTOCOL | call                                    | %timeit           | returns                                                                                                                      |
|------------------+-----------------------------------------+-------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|                3 | pickle.dumps(dummy)                     | 5.8 µs ± 33.5 ns  | b'\x80\x03c__main__\nDummy\nq\x00)\x81q\x01.'                                                                                |
|                4 | pickle.dumps(dummy)                     | 5.74 µs ± 18.8 ns | b'\x80\x03c__main__\nDummy\nq\x00)\x81q\x01.'                                                                                |
|                3 | pickle.dumps(dummy, protocol=4)         | 6.18 µs ± 10.4 ns | b'\x80\x04\x95\x1b\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x8c\x08__main__\x94\x8c\x05Dummy\x94\x93\x94)}\x94\x92\x94.'                  |
|                4 | pickle.dumps(dummy, protocol=4)         | 6.24 µs ± 26.7 ns | b'\x80\x04\x95\x1b\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x8c\x08__main__\x94\x8c\x05Dummy\x94\x93\x94)}\x94\x92\x94.'                  |
|                3 | pickle.dumps(packet_list_1)             | 476 ns ± 1.01 ns  | b'\x80\x03]q\x00cbuiltins\nrange\nq\x01K\x00K\x01K\x01\x87q\x02Rq\x03a.'                                                     |
|                4 | pickle.dumps(packet_list_1)             | 481 ns ± 2.12 ns  | b'\x80\x03]q\x00cbuiltins\nrange\nq\x01K\x00K\x01K\x01\x87q\x02Rq\x03a.'                                                     |
|                3 | pickle.dumps(packet_list_1, protocol=4) | 730 ns ± 2.22 ns  | b'\x80\x04\x95#\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00]\x94\x8c\x08builtins\x94\x8c\x05range\x94\x93\x94K\x00K\x01K\x01\x87\x94R\x94a.' |
|                4 | pickle.dumps(packet_list_1, protocol=4) | 733 ns ± 2.94 ns  | b'\x80\x04\x95#\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00]\x94\x8c\x08builtins\x94\x8c\x05range\x94\x93\x94K\x00K\x01K\x01\x87\x94R\x94a.' |
```

Notice how the `%timeit` results correspond well when we pair calls that give the same return value.

As you can see, the value of `pickle.DEFAULT_PROTOCOL`  has no effect on the value returned by `pickle.dumps`.
If the protocol parameter is not specified, the default protocol is 3 no matter what the value of `pickle.DEFAULT_PROTOCOL`.

The [reason is here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/pickle.py#L1570):

```
# Use the faster _pickle if possible
try:
    from _pickle import (
        PickleError,
        PicklingError,
        UnpicklingError,
        Pickler,
        Unpickler,
        dump,
        dumps,
        load,
        loads
    )
except ImportError:
    Pickler, Unpickler = _Pickler, _Unpickler
    dump, dumps, load, loads = _dump, _dumps, _load, _loads
```

The `pickle` module sets `pickle.dumps` to `_pickle.dumps` if it succeeds in importing `_pickle`, the compiled version of the pickle module.
The `_pickle` module uses `protocol=3` by default. Only if Python fails to import `_pickle` is `dumps` set to [the Python version](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/pickle.py#L1552):

```
def _dumps(obj, protocol=None, *, fix_imports=True):
    f = io.BytesIO()
    _Pickler(f, protocol, fix_imports=fix_imports).dump(obj)
    res = f.getvalue()
    assert isinstance(res, bytes_types)
    return res
```

Only the Python version, `_dumps`, is affected by the value of `pickle.DEFAULT_PROTOCOL`:

```
In [68]: pickle.DEFAULT_PROTOCOL = 3

In [70]: pickle._dumps(dummy)
Out[70]: b'\x80\x03c__main__\nDummy\nq\x00)\x81q\x01.'

In [71]: pickle.DEFAULT_PROTOCOL = 4

In [72]: pickle._dumps(dummy)
Out[72]: b'\x80\x04\x95\x1b\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x8c\x08__main__\x94\x8c\x05Dummy\x94\x93\x94)}\x94\x92\x94.'
```